# Can we calculate a measure with percentage in Power BI matrix

Tags: powerbi

Can we create a percentage measure in power BI over a matrix visual.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution? Please share with me. I also want to perform same action as I created a pivot table in matrix.

Comment: Eventually i tried converting it the source data itself. I.e. In sql query and used it in matrix. I think we cannot do percentage calculation in matrix visual i guess.

Comment: Actually I had to pivot and then create a measure to divide 2 columns. I did it using transform and then creating measure. You can try too, if you haven't. I am not 100% sure what exactly are you trying to achieve, what are you trying to divide really? Did you try clicking the arrows next to rows and column names and format? I could do that % formatting from there but after the division part was in place.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a measure in your table using DAX below -

```
% Percentage = DIVIDE([1],[0])
```

Then change the `format of [% Percentage]` to percentage

Comment: But this is not a table visual. I need to create it for matrix. The attached image is the summary.

Answer (score 0):

You can create this below measure-

```
%percentage = DIVIDE(your_table_name[1],your_tabl_name[0])
```

Now change the **Type** of the Measure as **%** from the top menu.

Comment: I need to create it for matrix visual.

Comment: Please show your original formatted sample data with your expected output. Question with partial information is confusing.

Comment: Check I have edited and updated my post with sample image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if it helps. I am throwing blank if denominator is blank else it's value will become invalid:

Create a measure and append that next to your matrix.

```
Measure = IF(COUNT(Sheet1[Denominator])<COUNT(Sheet1[Numerator]), BLANK(), DIVIDE(SUM(Sheet1[Numerator]), SUM(Sheet1[Denominator])))
```

Later you can change formatting from right side, below visualization, where you see small dropdowns next to column/row/values names > Show values as.

Let me know if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I created a Measure to calculate the percentage. Once it was correct, simply click on that measure so the formula shows at the top of your screen then on the Toolbar above change Format from General to Percentage. Voila!!